# Simple way to serve up image and render on page with Angular 6 and html img tag

Tags: javascript, angular, image

I have to serve some images to my client however I'm unsure of a clean, concise way to do this in Angular 6. A lot of the solutions I've looked into are convoluted or would bypass the middleware I have created. Does anyone know of any clean, concise ways of handling served images in Angular 6?? I want to send a token with the request and also need to be able to set src to a non-static url (e.g. 'localhost:3000/profile/' + imgLocation)

Comment: What sort of solutions were you looking at?  Unless you're trying to do something unusual, there's no need to do anything different here.

Answer (score 0):

To display an image, use the `img` tag, just like in plain HTML. There's nothing Angular-specific about handling images, as browsers to the work by themselves.

```
<img src="https://unsplash.it/600">
```

---

For a non-static URL, you can use Angular's binding to change it whenever the model changes. If you have a class property `imageUrl`, you can bind it using the `[]` syntax:

```
<img [src]="imageUrl">
```

Now, whenever you change the `imageUrl` property, that change will be reflected in the DOM.

Comment: I understand that but how would I attach a token to the header or if the url is variable how would I achieve a non-static src url??

Comment: @Will I've updated my answer about "non-static URL" but I'm not sure what tokens or headers you're talking about. If you need to add something to `<head>`, but add it in the `index.html` file.